# Copying questions that had a misfortune of being widely exposed in the hot list

Tags: discussion, questions, quality, hot-questions

This question had a [misfortune](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217573/165773) to be widely exposed in the hot list:

- [Some of the employees don't check if everything has been flushed properly and that the bowl is clean](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20074/some-of-the-employees-dont-check-if-everything-has-been-flushed-properly-and-th/20076#20076)

Newer question is a slight variation of above, and is in the hot list too (why wouldn't it, having magic combination of words *toilet* and *manager* in the title):

- [What should I do about the discovery that a manager is not flushing the workplace toilet after use?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20318/what-should-i-do-about-the-discovery-that-a-manager-is-not-flushing-the-workplac)

What's our take on this?

---

**Update** As far as I can tell, we've got yet another case like described above. This question had a [misfortune](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217573/165773) to be widely exposed in the hot list:

- [How can I interact professionally with female colleagues whose appearance I find distracting?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36790/how-to-deal-if-female-colleagues-dressing-style-is-disturbing-me)

Newer question is a slight variation of above, although it is not yet in the hot list:

- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/how-to-deal-if-colleagues-dressing-style-is-disturbing-me

Comment: Hot is good, right? Gaming the system, perhaps? Sort of like SEO, but at the stackexchange level? (It's good to know that *toilet* and *manager* are magic words.)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere oh there are plenty magic combinations to trigger lemmings attention. ["git is fantastic"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164078/165773) does the trick. Anything ["sexual"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/148323/11429) in the title does it, too. It's not a rocket science, really

Comment: LOL. Funny stuff this "reputation score" thing. You get what you encourage.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere by the way, there was a time when this was a problem at Stack Overflow, see: [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/). They seem to have solved it since, likely by dumping troublesome categories of questions to Programmers, Workplace, Code Golf, UX etc...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm for quickly/proactively dup-closing such candidates.

Which implies the need for active voters with the same opinion or mods who just go ahead and do it.

Comment: Ah I thought, dups were supposed to be kept around for SEO reasons. If that's not the case, by all means let's clean them up

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware those two were one user

Comment: Ohh you are right, they are different...

Comment: Duplicates that are asked differently enough can be valuable (if actually closed as dupes of course); the same question can be asked in different ways and this helps with searching.  Duplicates that are nearly identical to the originals (as in the second example in the question, now deleted) are not valuable and can be deleted.  So can badly-asked ones.  When evaluating, ask yourself if you can imagine somebody reasonably getting to the dupe via Google; if the answer is yes, it's probably worth keeping (absent any other problems of course).