# Broken Windows for Review Week #2

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, broken-windows-review

#### Broken Windows for Review Week #2

As part of our [efforts to help fix closed questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2891/repairing-our-broken-windows-we-need-your-help) on our site, below are ten Workplace SE questions posted for community review. We'll leave this post open until Sunday, September 7th, and then we'll handle whatever remains.

Tools at your disposal include editing, voting to delete or voting to reopen, and you may discuss the questions in chat and on meta.

If you wish to start a meta discussion about one of the posts, please use one answer below per question, and then use the comments underneath that answer to discuss that post. This helps keep information about a post in one spot:

1. [Send wedding invitations to some co-workers but not all](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31691/how-to-deal-with-sending-wedding-invitations)
2. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/how-do-i-deal-with-a-colleague-who-wears-socks-and-sandals-to-work
3. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/29377/prevalence-of-offshoring-in-the-information-security-industry
4. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31790/delayed-start-date-and-compensation
5. [Don't know if my company uses employee monitoring software - how to adjust behavior?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30908/how-widespread-is-the-usage-of-employee-monitoring-software)
6. [How to deal with less productive days?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30716/how-to-deal-with-less-productive-days)
7. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/as-a-web-developer-how-can-i-determine-whether-to-focus-on-contract-work-or-sta
8. [How to push back when colleagues send work to me they can do themselves?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31112/how-to-push-back-when-colleagues-send-work-to-me-they-can-do-themselves)
9. [Is there a best practice for word choice on resumes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/normal-verbiage-on-resume)
10. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31075/how-to-deal-with-a-touchy-irritable-supervisor-who-is-much-older

Comment: I put some delete votes on some, and others already had one so there are a few with 2 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results:

1. [Send wedding invitations to some co-workers but not all](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31691/how-to-deal-with-sending-wedding-invitations)

Reopened (with a mod casting the fifth vote).

2. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/how-do-i-deal-with-a-colleague-who-wears-socks-and-sandals-to-work

Deleted by the community.

3. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/29377/prevalence-of-offshoring-in-the-information-security-industry

No activity.  Deleted.

4. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31790/delayed-start-date-and-compensation

No improvements during the review; OP hasn't been back since asking it; one delete vote from the community.  Deleted.

5. [Don't know if my company uses employee monitoring software - how to adjust behavior?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30908/how-widespread-is-the-usage-of-employee-monitoring-software)

This received a major edit, and the meta answer supporting it has two upvotes.  The question has not yet been reopened.  No further action at this time.

6. [How to deal with less productive days?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30716/how-to-deal-with-less-productive-days)

The meta post supporting this one has three upvotes.  The question has no current reopen votes (votes age away and can't be recast when that happens).  We're going to leave this one alone for now.

7. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/as-a-web-developer-how-can-i-determine-whether-to-focus-on-contract-work-or-sta

Received one delete vote; no other activity.  Deleted.

8. [How to push back when colleagues send work to me they can do themselves?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31112/how-to-push-back-when-colleagues-send-work-to-me-they-can-do-themselves)

Edited and reopened by the community.

9. [Is there a best practice for word choice on resumes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/normal-verbiage-on-resume)

This was edited but not yet reopened.  We carried this forward to the next list to give the community more time to review it.

10. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31075/how-to-deal-with-a-touchy-irritable-supervisor-who-is-much-older

Received one delete vote; no other activity.  Deleted.

Two reopened, two improved but not yet reopened (please take another look), five deleted, one left alone.

Answer (score 5):

**1 [Send wedding invitations to some co-workers but not all](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31691/how-to-deal-with-sending-wedding-invitations)**

I think there is a good question in here: in a situation where you interact with lots of coworkers on a regular basis, how do you go about only inviting *some* of them to an event (in this case a wedding)?  I think an edit that refines the "how do I deal with it?" language into a request for practical steps to take to do this without causing workplace strife could save it.  The top two answers seem valuable; one answers how to do it and the other offers a workaround to soothe ruffled feathers.

Comment: I tried rephrasing my question and edited the title. But if that doesn't suffice, I would appreciate an edit to make it a fit for the SE format.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi thanks for the edit!  That looks much better to me.

Comment: Thanks! I voted for reopening.

Comment: Would need 1 more reopen vote.

Comment: This got four reopen votes from the community, so I cast the fifth one.

Answer (score 4):

8 [**How to push back when colleagues send work to me they can do themselves?**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31112/how-to-push-back-when-colleagues-send-work-to-me-they-can-do-themselves)

This was closed as "unclear", yet seems clear enough now.
Perhaps it became clearer after the edits?

Comment: I've proposed an edit which makes the question a bit more clearly match the question title and doesn't really invalidate the top two answers. If accepted, that edit should kick it into the reopen queue.

Comment: For what it's worth, two close votes were cast before the edit on July 23 and two after.  With Matt's edit today it now has two reopen votes.

Comment: This has been reopened.

Answer (score 3):

6 **[How to deal with less productive days?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30716/how-to-deal-with-less-productive-days)**

This one got a fair number of upvotes and an accepted answer. Is it worth deleting?

Comment: If you cast a reopen vote, @JoeStrazzere, it will push that in the [reopen review queue](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen). There are only 3 posts there, so that would get this a ton of attention.

Comment: @jmort253 - thanks, but I've already done that.

Answer (score 3):

### 2. [How do I deal with a colleague who wears socks and sandals to work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/30889/18336)

The question reads almost like the OP was trolling, probably unintentional under the auspices of humor but it also has a personal attack as well.

The body contains statements like...

> Constantly mock him into submission.
>
> I should also add this colleague is quite eccentric and has been know to cut his hair in the style of Martin Luther.

The question as written is pretty bad and could be deleted completely without much second thought. I feel there is a question here about approaching a coworker about a dress code issue, I browsed the [dress-code](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dress-code) tag for something similar to no avail. The edits would have to be drastic to to the effect that it might be easier to just ask it again after deleting this one.

Comment: This has been deleted by three votes from the community.

Answer (score 2):

**5 [Don't know if my company uses employee monitoring software - how to adjust behavior?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30908/how-widespread-is-the-usage-of-employee-monitoring-software)**

The original post was speculative and overly broad. However, the post has been edited and is a bit more fitting for Q&A format. This post does still seem a *little* broad, but the answers fit the goals of our site, which is to teach, not just tell.

The answerers take into account different possible scenarios, without making assumptions about the asker's situation, and these answers provide possible ways that the asker might approach finding an answer that matches that person's workplace.

Since it focuses on the *how*, it's possible that future visitors to this question can also use the information in the answers to find out if their workplace monitors employees and how they should approach the use of the Internet in their own workplace.

While closing this question was the right move, this is an area where our community of close/reopen voters should definitely circle back and review this post and to possibly [vote to reopen](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: I answered this question and made an edit that didn't quite bring it back. I'm not sure how to edit it further, but after seeing the great work done to save other questions in last week's group, I hope this one can be saved as well

Comment: @MattGiltaji - I think one concern might be that the answers don't address the full question in its current format. As an example, do the answers address how to behave in the presence of monitoring software? Either that info is missing, or perhaps we just need to highlight that better so it's more obvious to readers.

Comment: The question in the title ("how widespread...") is not the same as the question in the body ("how can I tell, and how should I modify my behavior").  One answer addresses the question in the title; the other answer addresses both.  Perhaps the question should be reworked to match the one in the body (which would be on-topic, unlike the title) and the answers adjusted.

Comment: I've edited the title to match the question body, and updated my answer to reflect the "how to behave" aspect of the question.