# Broken Windows for Review Week #3

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, broken-windows-review

#### Broken Windows for Review Week #3

As part of our [efforts to help fix closed questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2891/repairing-our-broken-windows-we-need-your-help) on our site, below are ten Workplace SE questions posted for community review. We'll leave this post open until Sunday, September 14th, and then we'll handle whatever remains.

Tools at your disposal include editing, voting to delete or voting to reopen, and you may discuss the questions in chat and on meta.

If you wish to start a meta discussion about one of the posts, please use one answer below per question, and then use the comments underneath that answer to discuss that post. This helps keep information about a post in one spot:

1. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31650/is-it-common-for-the-workforce-to-not-be-educated-about-about-relieving-letters
2. [Best way to communicate that there is too much work to do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31478/best-way-to-communicate-that-there-is-too-much-work-to-do)
3. [Is it okay to use an office printer to print personal documents?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31568/is-it-okay-to-use-an-office-printer-to-print-personal-documents)
4. [Is there a best practice for word choice on resumes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/normal-verbiage-on-resume) (carry-over from last week, where it received some help but needs more; please take another look)
5. [Last Day and Medical Coverage](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31560/last-day-and-medical-coverage)
   (auto-deleted by [roomba script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773))
6. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31521/what-to-do-when-your-office-loses-electricity
7. [How can I determine whether or not I should ask for a raise, and how do I approach my boss with this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31409/how-can-i-determine-whether-or-not-i-should-ask-for-a-raise-and-how-do-i-approa)
8. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/what-to-do-when-you-are-in-an-internal-interview-process-and-current-manager-off
9. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31487/is-there-an-expected-behaviour-when-you-keep-running-into-someone-at-work-can-y
10. [Reducing the salary after job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/reducing-the-salary-after-job-offer)

Comment: #2 should be a duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10456/16

Comment: #7 is a duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/underpaid-and-overworked-how-should-i-approach-my-boss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results:

1. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31650/is-it-common-for-the-workforce-to-not-be-educated-about-about-relieving-letters

Deleted.

2. [Best way to communicate that there is too much work to do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31478/best-way-to-communicate-that-there-is-too-much-work-to-do)

Proposed (in a comment) as a duplicate of [How can we protest a deadline that is too short?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10456/16).  Did that.

3. [Is it okay to use an office printer to print personal documents?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31568/is-it-okay-to-use-an-office-printer-to-print-personal-documents)

This got a small number of mixed opinions.  It currently has one delete vote.  No action at this time; anybody should feel free to edit to make it more clearly on-topic, or bring it up in a new meta post, or vote to delete.

4. [Is there a best practice for word choice on resumes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/normal-verbiage-on-resume) (carry-over from last week, where it received some help but needs more; please take another look)

This has been edited, had lukewarm support on meta, and has two reopen votes that aged out.  No action taken at this time; anybody who feels strongly for either reopening or deletion is invited to raise it in a new meta post.

5. [Last Day and Medical Coverage](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31560/last-day-and-medical-coverage)

This was auto-deleted by the [roomba script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773) during the review.  Nobody objected.

6. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31521/what-to-do-when-your-office-loses-electricity

Deleted.

7. [How can I determine whether or not I should ask for a raise, and how do I approach my boss with this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31409/how-can-i-determine-whether-or-not-i-should-ask-for-a-raise-and-how-do-i-approa)

Proposed (in a comment) as a duplicate of [Underpaid and overworked, how should I approach my boss?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/underpaid-and-overworked-how-should-i-approach-my-boss).  Went with that.

8. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/what-to-do-when-you-are-in-an-internal-interview-process-and-current-manager-off

No discussion on meta and the OP hasn't been back since August 1.  Deleted.

9. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31487/is-there-an-expected-behaviour-when-you-keep-running-into-someone-at-work-can-y

Deleted.

10. [Reducing the salary after job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/reducing-the-salary-after-job-offer)

Edited and reopened by the community.

**Summary:** 1 edited and reopened, 2 re-closed as duplicates, 1 improved but still closed, 1 no action, 5 deleted.

Answer (score 4):

#### 10. [Reducing the salary after job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/reducing-the-salary-after-job-offer)

This question is upvoted fairly highly and has several highly voted answers, including one answer with ***one hundred upvotes***. I think it's safe to say that the community agrees with the usefulness of that answer.

I think we can and should edit to save this question.

Comment: lots of upvotes don't mean usefulness, see [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/). I would expect more solid explanation for why posts are useful ([another answer](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2925/168) also uses the broken logic about lots-upvotes but it at least complements it with more tangible reasoning)

Comment: While the question itself is short, the answers expand on the theme enough to make the package useful. I think that's why the community agreed on the usefulness with its votes. It seems like a real question to me. I don't understand why it was closed.

Comment: I made an edit that I think brings it back towards good subjective and does not invalidate Joe's great answer.  Let me know if you agree

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame very nicely done. I'd vote to reopen if I had the privilege.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame as far as I can tell, changes made to question invalidated (partly) two top answers which referred "unethical". Possibly other answers were affected as well

Comment: If people agree that the edit saves the question, answers can be edited.

Comment: @Gnat - The answers are not invalidated just because they address something that is no longer in the question.  The answers still address the current question which is important.  The ethics are off topic here.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame did you read these answers? they quote and address text which is not in the question. Having top answers so much out of sync with the questions asked is probably not quite okay even in closed question, but if it gets reopened, what signal is this going to send to site visitors?

Comment: I dont really see the problem.  The answer can remove the quotes and with just a minor effort be a quality answer.

Comment: And the second answer is horrible reguardless of how highly voted it is.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame (why will you get back to Chad!:) ...just noticed, [yet another answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/reducing-the-salary-after-job-offer#comment81470_31350) that can make site visitors raise eyebrows after recent question edits. Probably not as harmful as other two, as it's "only" 3rd top and has "only" 12 upvotes but still...

Comment: I dont really see the problem with any of these.  There are other answers to questions that make far less sense.  I could link too 2 users that have hundreds of them.

Answer (score 3):

#### 8. [What to do when your office loses electricity?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/31521/18336)

If I could, I would vote to delete this question. Jmort put a comment down after one day to let the OP know it's off topic as written. OP has not returned to comment, clarify or edit. It's currently at -7 and closed. The answers, strictly speaking about the ones with positive votes say the same thing...ask your boss. Each company will have it's own policy to govern this, I don't think much of anything could be gleaned from the community.

Answer (score 1):

### 4. [Is there a best practice for word choice on resumes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/normal-verbiage-on-resume)

This question has been edited since it was closed and I think it is a decent question that can be answered and is in scope.  The title could be better but the question it self should be ok.

Comment: It still seems really objective to me. They look like very minor word tweaks.

Comment: @yochannah Objective is a good thing...  Sometimes minor tweeks are all it takes to turn a bad question good.  And subjective isnt bad if it is focused and answerable.  See [Good subjective Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [Real Questions have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: I have no idea how I managed to type objective when I meant subjective. oops.

Comment: It is subjective but I think it is good subjective now.

Answer (score -1):

#### 3.  [Is it okay to use an office printer to print personal documents?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31568/is-it-okay-to-use-an-office-printer-to-print-personal-documents)

Highly upvoted, and in my opinion extremely likely to reoccur if deleted.  Also it seems like the close reason is inappropriate, as based upon my reading of the question the OP is asking if it is *generally* okay to print personal things on an office printer.

The OP was not asking for an answer specific to their company, and I think that while this may technically be a company-specific policy, in the *vast* majority of cases the policy is "personal use of company equipment is not allowed" (or near enough to that effect).  Thus closing the question for 'seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies' is excessively pedantic and the question should be reopened.

Comment: The only thing I Can see doing with this question is asking how to determine if it is ok.

Comment: That someone else might ask the same bad question in the future is not a good reason to keep a bad question around.